# Re-run python script after error in batch

Tags: python, batch-file, error-handling

I have this python script using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) to listen for messages from certain bot and do something after a message. Problem is it throws some error after some time so I'm looking for a way to re run it using batch.

Is there any way to catch the error and just run `py main.py` again after?

Comment: We expect a [mcve] for coding problems on this site. Without it, you probably chose the wrong platform for your question. BTW, I added [[tag:python]], and [[tag:error-handling]] tags, to your question, the former being essential based upon your current content. Please consider targeting an appropriate audience and helping them if you wish them to reciprocate.

Comment: There can be used a label in the batch file like `:ReRun` and next line is `%SystemRoot%\System32\py.exe "%~dp0main.py" || goto ReRun` with expecting by this command line that `main.py` is stored in same directory as the batch file with file extension `.cmd`. The command line expects an exit of `py.exe` respectively the started `python.exe` with an exit code greater or equal `1` on execution of the script `main.py` stopped because of an error caused most likely by not good code. The Python script should be improved to fix the cause of the error.